# Why does the EFFs unique-prefix-wordlist have so long words

Tags: passwords, passphrase

A while ago, the EFF [published new wordlists to be used with diceware](https://www.eff.org/de/deeplinks/2016/07/new-wordlists-random-passphrases), to create passphrases with “better” words.

One variant is the “[short word list (with words that have unique three-character prefixes)](https://www.eff.org/files/2016/09/08/eff_short_wordlist_2_0.txt)”. They write about this list

> Finally, we're publishing one more short list [.txt] which with a few  additional features making the words easy to type:
>
> - Each word has a unique three-character prefix. This means that future software could auto-complete words in the passphrase after the user has typed the first three characters
> - All words are at least an edit distance of 3 apart. This means that future software could correct any single typo in the user's passphrase (and in many cases more than one typo).
>
> We've added these features in the hope that they might be used by software in the future that was specially designed to take advantage of them, but will not offer a significant benefit today so this list is mostly a proof-of-concept for individual users. Software developers might be able to find interesting uses for this list.

But why would they hope for software developers to implement auto-complete? Couldn’t they just tell the users “remember the whole world, but just type the first three characters” to get the same effect – no loss of security, but shorter passphrases?

Also, I noticed that the list contains words like `viperfish` that seem awfully redundant – wouldn’t the shorter word `viper` work just as well in its place? Similarly, `mapmaker` could just be `map`, `capsule` could be `cap`, `older` could be `old`. Is there a reason why they have not just chosen the simplest, shortest english word for a given three-letter prefix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `cap`, `old` and (presumably) `viper` would ruin the edit distance guarantee.

I imagine that users don't want to just type the first three letters - it can be less mental effort to type words. There's another common scheme where you take a longer sequence of words and include only the first letter from each word: Which approach you prefer is largely a matter of taste.

Comment: Yeah, the edit distance is it, I guess. Not sure how it helps if you have auto-complete after 3 characters.